# Dart forcing me to implement non abstract method in child class

Tags: dart

I am trying abstract classes I found one issue that I have to implement the non-abstract method having a body in child classes

code:

```
abstract class Animal{
void breathe(); //abstract method

void makeNoise(){
//non abstract method
print('making animal noises!');
}
}

abstract class IsFunny{
void makePeopleLaugh();//abstract method
}

class TVShow implements IsFunny{
String name;

@override
void makePeopleLaugh() {
// TODO: implement makePeopleLaugh
print("TV show is funny and make people laugh");
}
}

class Comedian extends Person implements IsFunny{
Comedian(String name, String nation) : super(name, nation);

@override
void makePeopleLaugh() {
// TODO: implement makePeopleLaugh
print('make people laugh');
}
}

class Person implements Animal{
String name,nation;

Person(this.name,this.nation);

//we must implement all the methods present in Abstract class and child should override the abstract methods
@override
void breathe() {
// TODO: implement breathe
print('person breathing through nostrils!');
}

//there should be no compulsion to override non abstract method
@override
void makeNoise() {
// TODO: implement makeNoise
print('shouting!');
}

}

void main(List arguments) {
var swapnil=new Person('swapnil','India');
swapnil.makeNoise();
swapnil.breathe();
print('${swapnil.name},${swapnil.nation}');
}
```

here I am trying not to implement makeNoise method in my Person class but it gives error and says abstract method must be implemented.

Is this bug or I am getting concept wrong

Comment: It's because `Person` is *implementing* `Animal`, not extending it. https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/implements-v-s-extends-v-s-with-keywords-in-dart

Comment: yes I got it I was getting the concept wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution after some time I understood that when inheriting abstract class I should have used extends keyword instead of implements due to which dart was telling me to also implement the non-abstract method as it is compulsory to implement all methods when using interfaces.
I think my question was **silly**

Answer (score 11):

You are using `implements`, which is used for interfaces, not for inheritance. The keyword you are looking for is `extends`.

```dart
abstract class Foo {
  void doThing() {
    print("I did a thing");
  }

  void doAnotherThing();
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  @override
  void doAnotherThing() {
    print("I did another thing");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a bug. The method is still in an abstract class that you are *implementing*. I think that you instead intended to *extend* the class in which case you would call `super.makeNoise()` in the override.

Comment: @robinsax made a similar comment on the original question a second before me that has a useful link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixin if you have two class for extend:

```
mixin OnComplete {
  void onFirst() {
    // not compulsory to override this
  }

  void onSecond();
}

class B {
  // Class B implementation
}

class A extends B with OnComplete {
  // Class A implementation
}
```